# Search through a nested list using an if statement

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to take elements out of a nested list that have values below 50 and the corresponding values with them to display them. I tried making it, but it's giving me nothing.

Here is the code:

```
newList = ["payroll", "accounting", "security", "office", "sales"]
deptNums = [10 * index for index in range(1, 16)]
deptInfo = [[]]

for row in range(0, len(newList)) :
    deptInfo.append([newList[row], deptNums[row]])
print(deptInfo)

belowFifty = []
for items in deptInfo:
        if (50 > deptNums[row]):
            belowFifty.append(newList[row],deptNums[row])
print(belowFifty)
```

Comment: I don't understand your second loop: iterating variable`items` is nowhere used?

Comment: You are also using the `row` variable, which is left over as `4` from the previous loop, and since `deptNums[4] == 50`, the `if` statement is not true for any iteration.

Comment: I tried putting deptNums[items] first, but it gave me an error, "list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not iterating variable 'row' in the second for loop. the scope of variable 'row' ends with the first for loop.A more appropriate code:

```
newList = ["payroll", "accounting", "security", "office", "sales"]
deptNums = [10 * index for index in range(1, 16)]
deptInfo = [[]]

for row in range(0, len(newList)) :
    deptInfo.append([newList[row], deptNums[row]])
print(deptInfo)

belowFifty = []
for item, number in zip(newList, deptNums):
    if 50 > number:
        belowFifty.append([item, number])
print(belowFifty)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `deptInfo`.

Just do this:

```
belowFifty = []
for row in range(len(deptNums)):
    if (50 > deptNums[row]):
        belowFifty.append([newList[row],deptNums[row]])

belowFifty
```

Output:

```
[['payroll', 10], ['accounting', 20], ['security', 30], ['office', 40]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:
1. You are initializing `deptInfo` as `[[]]`, hence after the appends you get:

```
[[],
 ['payroll', 10],
 ['accounting', 20],
 ['security', 30],
 ['office', 40],
 ['sales', 50]]
```

2. You are iterating over the items in `deptInfo` but trying to check `deptNum` with indices (`row`) that was the previous iteration variable, which currently has a value `5`, and `deptNum[5]` has a value of `60`, so your `if` does not check anything. Here is your fixed code:

```
newList = ["payroll", "accounting", "security", "office", "sales"]
deptNums = [10 * index for index in range(1, 16)]
deptInfo = []

for row in range(0, len(newList)) :
    deptInfo.append([newList[row], deptNums[row]])
print(deptInfo)
belowFifty = []
for items in deptInfo:
        if (50 > items[1]):
            belowFifty.append(items)
print(belowFifty)
```

Now here's a shortened code:

```
newList = ["payroll", "accounting", "security", "office", "sales"]
deptNums = [10 * index for index in range(1, 16)]
print([[i,j] for i,j in zip(newList, deptNums) if j < 50])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A short-hand approach using list comprehension rather than conventional loops.

Is this what you're after?  This example uses the [`zip()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) function and [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3).

Basically, the `zip` function aligns the two lists and iterates them together - so here, we can put your department names and department numbers together and **iterate them as a pair**.

```
newList = ["payroll", "accounting", "security", "office", "sales"]
# I edited this to match the length of your department names.
deptNums = [10 * index for index in range(1, len(newList))]

# Use list comprehension to iterate, test and create a new list all in ONE line.
deptInfo = [[num, dpt] for num, dpt in zip(newList, deptNums) if dpt < 50]
```

#### Output:

```
[['payroll', 10], ['accounting', 20], ['security', 30], ['office', 40]]
```